# Which Android API level to choose for developing Shopping Application like Amazon or Alibaba

Tags: android, android-studio

Would you be so pleased to help to choose the API level for android application to develop a shopping app like Amazon and Alibaba?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go with **API level 21**, as it will support **85%** of current running devices. You will get support of Material design and all animations support.

**Update:** Try to follow MVVM Pattern, Live data and Room if your application contains local database.